# How to remove duplicates in map()

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

How to remove duplicates in `[].map()` . `a.href` may contain the same `href` link, how can I stop this reoccuring data? EXAMPLE: www.example.com | www.example.com

```js
const hrefs = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a');
    return [].map.call(anchors, a => a.href);
});
```

Comment: Put them in a `Set` object and you then iterate them from there or convert that back to an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Set hrefs = new Set([].map.call(anchors, a => a.href));
return [...hrefs];
```